# PySpark toPandas() gives TypeError: Unexpected obj type: <class 'int'>

Tags: pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I have a spark dataframe df, with 2 columns and the following datatype

```
root
 |-- session_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
```

then I want to convert it to Pandas dataframe using `df.toPandas()`. I received the following error `TypeError: Unexpected obj type: <class 'int'>`

I have no `int` type in my spark dataframe, and dropna already. A bit confused why this is happening, any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the revelant snippet of code where the error occurs along with input rows?